# Where are "known peripherals" stored, and for how long?

Tags: ios, uuid, core-bluetooth

The CBCentralManager method [`retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBCentralManager/retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:)

> Returns a list of known peripherals by their identifiers.

...when passed a list of UUIDs.

Where are these identifiers stored, and for how long? Or are they generated from the supplied UUIDs?

Put another way, if my app stores the UUID of a device it's discovered in the normal way, and assuming that that device's UUID never changes, can I use `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:` at any point in the future with that UUID, instead of having to do another scan?

Related:

- [Trying to retrieve previously paired bluetooth device in IOS app will not respond with failure if device is off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18244137/trying-to-retrieve-previously-paired-bluetooth-device-in-ios-app-will-not-respon)
- [What, exactly, is a BLE connected device on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852662/what-exactly-is-a-ble-connected-device-on-ios)

**UPDATE**

From experimentation, it appears that the data is held in some app-specific storage, and so is lost when the app terminates.

I encountered some odd behaviour. If, after disconnecting from a device, the app invalidates its pointer to the CBPeripheral, later retrieves one using `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers`, and uses this to connect, then nothing happens.

However, if the app never invalidates its pointer, and uses this (instead of the retrieved value) to connect, then everything works fine.

However, this defeats the point of doing the retrieval in the first place. So am I missing something here?